# PostgreSQL duplicate key violates unique constraint error

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

CentOS 6.2 64bit Server
PostgreSQL 8.4.9 installed via yum

I am seeing errors from time to time in PostgreSQL's logs about a table called events.  The events table is used to stores information generated by triggers in Zabbix everytime a specific event occurs on a server that is being monitored.

Zabbix is the only application using the database server.

**Here is the error:**

```
INSTRUCTION :  insert into events (eventid,source,object,objectid,clock,ns,value,value_changed) values (6393428,2,3,38,1353354000,0,1,0)
ERROR:  duplicate key violates unique constraint « events_pkey »
```

There is no sequence associated with the table events

**Here is the table structure for events**

```
                               Table « public.events »
    Colonne    |  Type   |          Modificateurs           | Stockage | Description 
---------------+---------+----------------------------------+----------+-------------
 eventid       | bigint  | non NULL                         | plain    | 
 source        | integer | non NULL Par défaut, 0           | plain    | 
 object        | integer | non NULL Par défaut, 0           | plain    | 
 objectid      | bigint  | non NULL Par défaut, (0)::bigint | plain    | 
 clock         | integer | non NULL Par défaut, 0           | plain    | 
 value         | integer | non NULL Par défaut, 0           | plain    | 
 acknowledged  | integer | non NULL Par défaut, 0           | plain    | 
 ns            | integer | non NULL Par défaut, 0           | plain    | 
 value_changed | integer | non NULL Par défaut, 0           | plain    | 
Index :
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (eventid)
    "events_1" btree (object, objectid, eventid)
    "events_2" btree (clock)
Référencé par :
    TABLE "acknowledges" CONSTRAINT "c_acknowledges_2" FOREIGN KEY (eventid) REFERENCES events(eventid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "alerts" CONSTRAINT "c_alerts_2" FOREIGN KEY (eventid) REFERENCES events(eventid) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**Question**

What steps can I take to resolve this error?

Thank you

**Updated 11/26**

I tried to run the ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN statement that dezso sent me, but I get an error about the bigserial type.

```
zabbix=# ALTER TABLE events ALTER COLUMN eventid TYPE bigserial;
ERREUR:  le type « bigserial » n'existe pas
```

I can however create a new table with that data type

```
zabbix=# \connect postgres
psql (8.4.13)
Vous êtes maintenant connecté à la base de données « postgres ».
postgres=# CREATE TABLE test(x bigserial);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE créera des séquences implicites « test_x_seq » pour la colonne serial « test.x »
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# \ds
              Liste des relations
 Schéma |    Nom     |   Type   | Propriétaire 
--------+------------+----------+--------------
 public | test_x_seq | séquence | postgres
(1 ligne)
```

How should I go about changing eventid to bigserial?

**Update 11/27**

I have tried another method to add the sequence to the column eventid

```
create sequence eventid_seq;
alter table events alter column eventid set default nextval('eventid_seq');
select (max(eventid) +1) as nexteventid from events;
SELECT setval('eventid_seq', 6645754);
```

That worked, but when I turned Zabbix back on, the eventid value continued to increase but the sequence didn't.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventid = 6393428` return?  I'm sure it will return exactly one row, which will show that somehow the `eventid` generation gives back the wrong id.  Generally it is wiser to leave this to a sequence.  Another much used but quite bad option is to get `max(eventid) + 1`. In this latter case you have to be sure that between `eventid` generation and the insert no other inserts will succeed.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. It's pretty clear how to avoid that error: do not insert values that are already in the database. It's a problem of this Zabbix application, not a PostgreSQL problems (PostgreSQL simply does what it was told to do)

Comment: @dezso: using `max(eventid) + 1` is a horrible idea to generate primary keys.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is, but widely used.  I suspect a case of that here - I'll change the wording to clarify that, thanks.

Comment: How could I redefine the table to use a sequence to increment eventid without dropping the table and recreating it?

Comment: @CraigEfrein `ALTER TABLE events ALTER COLUMN eventid TYPE bigserial;`  After that you have to change your application code to either completely omit `eventid` field from the insert or get a `nextval()` before.  And you must set the starting value of the resulting sequence appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I try to compile an answer from the comments.)

It looks like there is a problem in the process with which your application generates the value for the primary key.  Generally it is wiser to leave this to the DBMS: define a sequence and leave it fill the PK values.  If you have a sequence, you have at least to options: either set the value like

```
$eventid = exec(SELECT nextval('your_sequence')) // pseudocode!
```

and use this in the `INSERT` statement, or completely leave it to PostgreSQL by omitting PK from the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO events (source, object, [...]) 
VALUES (2, 3, [...]);
```

(Personally I usually opt for the second solution.)

You can change to this behaviour by setting the data type of your PK column to `bigserial` (in case of an `integer`, it would be just `serial`):

```
ALTER TABLE events ALTER COLUMN eventid TYPE bigserial;
```

This will raise a notice which tells you that a sequence called (probably) `events_eventid_seq` is generated.  You can use it as described above.

### EDIT (2012-11-27)

You can set the sequence by a query like

```
SELECT setval('events_eventid_seq', (SELECT max(eventid) FROM events));
```

In order to let the sequence produce the next value for `eventid`, you must not set a value explicitly in your `INSERT`.  If you do, it will take the manually supplied value and won't advance the sequence.  This will cause the same unique violation error later.

Regarding `ALTER TABLE`: as you could see, there is some discrepancy between `ALTER TABLE` - type does not exists and `CREATE TABLE`.  Are you sure you try this on the same database?  I can't remember the older versions, but already 8.3 had the `bigserial` shorthand (it's not a real type).  (Giving it further thought, it is quite possible you can't use it in `ALTER TABLE`, since it is a shorthand...)  You can solve the problem by following the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE events_eventid_seq;

ALTER TABLE events 
ALTER COLUMN eventid TYPE bigint;

ALTER SEQUENCE events_eventid_seq OWNED BY events.eventid;

SELECT setval('events_eventid_seq', (SELECT max(eventid) FROM events));
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. I still need to test the modification on our preproduction server. I'll get back to you as soon as I have the results.

Comment: Updated my question.